# Django - being able to access page only after HttpResponseRedirect

Tags: python, django, redirect

I have a class based view in which I process the form and redirect the user on successful submission like so:

**views.py**

```
def get(self,request):
    form = self.form_class()
    return render(request, template_name, { 'form' : form })
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = self.form_class(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
            ...
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('success'))

return render(request, template_name, { 'form' : form })
```

**urls.py**

```
...
url(r'^submit/success', SubmitView.as_view(), name='success'),
...
```

It is possible to access url directly by typing success/submit. I don't use any authentication on the site and want the user only be able to access the submit/success page after redirection, so that they are not able to access it directly. How do I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using [sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/), you can accomplish it like so:

```
# in the view where form is submitted
if form.is_valid():
    request.session['form-submitted'] = True
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('success'))

# in the success view
def get(self, request):
    if not request.session.get('form-submitted', False):
        # handle case where form was not submitted
    else:
        # render the template
```

Comment: Does this also work for multi-tabbed/windows viewing?

Comment: depends on a browser. if the browser maintains the same session for all open windows/tabs, this approach should work.

Comment: That look like a viable solution. I will try to use sessions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of redirecting, you could `POST` to the 'success' page.
Then use `if request.method == 'POST':`
But beware, this is *NOT* secure, as headers can be spoofed.

Better to just call the success view from within the `POST` method, I think.

Comment: not a great idea to call the success view from within `POST` because the user then can refresh the page hence resubmit the form again, and again, and again, etc...

Comment: and its official recommended Django practice to return a redirect on form success

Comment: thought about this, but that look like a bad idea in general. Thanks for advice

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this:

```
if form.is_valid():
        ...
    return HttpResponseRedirect(SubmitView.as_view())
```

Not sure if this works out of the box, but with a few more tricks you might get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answer @miki725 posted I would also make sure you change

`request.session['form-submitted'] = False`

after you have entered the

`if not request.session.get('form-submitted', False):`

In order to prevent accessing the page directly or using the back and forward on the browser.